# How to make bootstrap buttons full width on resize only

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a set of 4 inline buttons at the top of my page, under a jumbotron.

2 are dropdowns, the others are just regular buttons.

when i resize the browser window, I'd like to make them change to vertical stacked, full width.  i know adding the class btn-block will make them full width, but i only want this to happen when the window size is less than 768px.

here's my current code.  thanks so much!

```
<div class="row">
<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Categories <b class="caret"></b></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</div>      
<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Archives <b class="caret"></b></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</div>      
<button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-fw"></i> Info</a>   </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Sign Up</a></button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a media query to apply the full width buttons at 768 pixels or less..

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .btn,.btn-group {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/98570

Comment: thank you!  I thought about doing this, but wasn't sure if there was something built into bootstrap i had missed that would do the same.  Thanks again!

Comment: thank you!! was having trouble getting around this. confirm works on bs 3.2

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend making a new class for these buttons, instead of overriding bootstrap.

```
.btn-mobile {
    width:100%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .btn-mobile {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

These extra styles aren't answering your question exactly, but if your intent is to use them on mobile, you may find the buttons too close together/skinny for mobile use (fingers are much fatter than mouse pointers).

```
.btn-mobile {
    width:100%;
    margin: 8px 0;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:1.33;
    border-radius:6px;
    padding:10px 16px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .btn-mobile {
    width: auto;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    padding:6px 12px;
  }
}
```